# Simple Java Game Graphical Interface

Tags: java, graphic

I am working on a game project in java and was wondering if anyone had any good advice for how to go about the graphical portion of it. My game will be a board game (similar to monopoly) and I would like to at least display a Monopoly-like board to the screen. After this, I would like the ability to dynamically adjust the board location of the game pieces (I don't need to have animations for the movement, but that would be cool)

Anyone know of any libraries that are useful for simple graphical interfaces such as this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/

Comment: You do not want to start with Java 2d.  Start with Swing, get something working, then move on to more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know of any libraries that are useful for simple graphical interfaces such as this?

See [AWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html#package_description) & [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#package_description).  Though AWT is the 'last millennium' GUI tool-kit, so I'd use Swing which adds extra abilities.

Comment: We should at least mention possibility number 3 which is used by lots of Java applications: [SWT](http://eclipse.org/swt/). Certainly better than AWT ;) Swing vs SWT is more interesting but I'm sure this was discussed to death on SO already.

Comment: @Voo Given SWT is too large to distribute for a 'simple game' & could most probably not be used by a sand-boxed app., I did not feel it was worth mentioning.

Comment: No idea about sandboxing, but you're right that it's certainly not a lightweight framework (well swing isn't either but that's not our problem). Also there are the crossplatform problems (the biggest problem imho) so it's certainly not without drawbacks, but I still think it's worth a look at least - although I hear swing has gotten much better in the last years.

Comment: @Voo, Swing may not have a small footprint but at least it comes with the language.

Comment: @Paul Sure, but is downloading 5mb or whatever the swt libs are in the days of 20mbit+ download speed (ie adding <4 seconds to the download) and 2tb hard disks really such a big problem that it's THE decision factor for deciding which framework to use?

Comment: *"20mbit+ download speed"*  Wow, you have fat wires.  My wireless internet would have trouble hitting 100Kb/sec.  As to the 'sand-boxed' aspect, I vaguely recall that SWT uses natives, which are not available to a sand-boxed app.

Answer (score 1):

swing would be one of your best options if your new to graphics in java, and if you would like to know more about swing and graphics go here: [Swing Graphics](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/java/swing/graphics.html) Also I would recommend staying away from Java2D until you feel you are ready to work on that. Oh, here is a link for AWT graphics, which is what i'm using right now: [Graphics (Java SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) Let me know if you would like to see an example and I can add that in too.
*EDIT*
Swing is relatively similar to AWT, apart from the fact that swing has more capabilities, AWT is probably the simplest form to start out with, and has most if not all of the tools to complete your project, hope this helps.